# Record audio on multiple tracks simultaneously from multiple devices

Tags: javascript, web, web-audio-api

I'm currenly developing an audio web application  using Web Audio API in javascript, but I found a problem: I need to record simultaneously from different devices to different tracks (imagine for example a sound card with 8 inputs recording in 8 buffers independently in orderto record a drummer), but I have not found any way to tell the AudioContext from which device you must record :(

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: sounds like a job for web-sockets and a node server if you want to use js. However recording audio on a phone is often rather tricky with out native access from an app.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can have multiple microphones - but only if they're plugged into a multi-channel interface.  Separate devices *would* be addressed by calling getUserMedia multiple times with a constraint to select different inputs - look at https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/index.html.  I'm not sure if we're wired up to support that yet, though.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that. The idea is that users can plug in a USB/firewire interface with multiple inputs / outputs and can record from the browser (think of cubase, for example). 
I have some experience programming Asio client applications to do that in the OS, but here i do not have a driver 'below' the application, but a web browser. 
Nice thing about this approach is portability, but it is not as efficient as in c ++ (although web-audio is supposed to be natively implemented) and you don't get such hadware control.
And all this must be done in client, to make the application scalable

Comment: Well you should be able to do that on a single interface - they'll just show up as multiple channels in the output you get from the MediaStreamSourceNode.

Comment: They don't though. No matter how many channels the interface you choose as input has, the MediaStreamSourceNode has a channelCount of 2. Setting channelInterpretation to 'discrete' and manually setting channelCount higher simply produces silent channels.

Comment: Limitation in Chrome's current implementation.  Should be implemented in the future.

Comment: @cwilso Does this limitation get removed?

Comment: Still a bug in Chrome as of 4/2/2022 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453876